# Asp Response.Redirect without UrlEncoding

Tags: asp-classic, url-encoding, response.redirect

I'm using Response.Redirect  to redirect users to some user specified urls.

The "problem" arises as users specifies urls as www.æøå.dk, which is a legal url, but is encoded as the following by Response.Redirect:

www.%c3%a6%c3%b8%c3%a5.dk 
- since æøå is considered special characters. Is there any way to allow æøå not to be encoded?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Such a domain is called an [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name). You may get further using [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx). There is a section called "International Resource Identifier Support" on that page.

Comment: The question is about classic ASP, System.Uri is not available there